# Make click-event on "responsive" dropdown item in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, maven, click

I have a maven-project and get the users via a spark get-call from a database:

```
    function allUsers(){
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json', //to parse string into JSON object
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'webAthen/api/users',
            success: function (data){
                $('.userDropdown').html("");

                for(i=0; i < data.length; i++){
                   $('.userDropdown').append("<option>" + data[i].userName + "</option>");
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Know if I click on such a user in the Dropbox, I want the information of this user right in labels like:

```
$('.userDropdown').val().click(function(){
        alert($('.userDropdown').val() + " was clicked :-)");

});
```

I inserted the alert to get an alert with the username that was clicked, but it doesn't work at all. If you need further code, just let me know! I already googled and found some examples with firm values. But my dropdown-entries are kind of dynamically from the database.

[image]

Comment: Why $('.userDropdown').val() ?

Comment: Are you able to provide your html markdown for `.dropdown`. Looks like you don't pass value to your option. Try the following:
`$('.userDropdown').append("<option value='" +data[i].userName + "'>" + data[i].userName + "</option>");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at your code, I feel like, the `option` tags are created dynamically. So the newly created options/elements are not bound by `Click` listener.

```
$(document).on("click", ".userDropdown > option", function(){
        // Your code...
});
```

The above code will Listen to the `onClick` event of `document` first, and later it's narrowed down to the targeted element.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation as well - helps a lot!